# Reemplazar ceros de una matriz usando una lista

Tags: python, pandas, matrices, bucles, numpy

He creado una lista llamada **ingreso_datos**, dentro de la cual ingreso información, noten que al trabajar con bucles for en mis variables visualizo el resultado de la última lista, es decir, del elemento 15, aquí dejo el excel: [ejercicio_ec](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lBPuwanPtJXn1oF9)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He creado una matriz de ceros de 36x36, además, he creado otra lista llamada **counters**, que me indica las filas y columnas a las que debo reemplazar los ceros de mi matriz creada anteriormente.

Los valores que voy a reemplazar en la matriz de ceros vienen dados por otra matriz, esta de 6x6, llamada **la_matriz**.

Mi problema está en que al hacer esto con un bucle for, me sale *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intertuples'.*

Esta semana estoy aprendiendo la manipulación de matrices en Python por lo que agradezco mucho la retroalimentación a estas dudas, saludos.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base = pd.ExcelFile('ejercicio_ec.xlsx')

ingreso_datos = [[ 1,    'W',    28,    29,    30,    19,    20,     21,      0,      0,      0,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 2,    'W',    31,    32,    33,    22,    23,      24,    4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 3,    'W',    34,    35,    36,    25,    26,      27,    9.5,      0,    9.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 4,    'W',    19,    20,    21,    10,    11,      12,      0,    2.5,      0,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 5,    'W',    22,    23,    24,    13,    14,     15,    4.5,    2.5,    4.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 6,    'W',    25,    26,    27,     6,    17,      18,    9.5,    2.5,    9.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 7,    'W',    10,    11,    12,     1,     2,       3,      0,      5,      0,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 8,    'W',    13,    14,    15,     4,     5,       6,    4.5,      5,    4.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 9,    'W',    16,    17,    18,     7,     8,       9,    9.5,      5,    9.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [10,    'X',      19,    20,    21,    22,    23,       24,      0,    2.5,    4.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [11,    'X',      22,    23,    24,    25,    26,       27,    4.5,    2.5,    9.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [12,    'X',      10,    11,    12,    13,    14,       15,      0,      5,    4.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [13,    'X',      13,    14,    15,    16,    17,       18,    4.5,      5,    9.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [14,    'X',       1,     2,     3,     4,     5,        6,      0,    7.5,    4.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [15,    'X',       4,     5,     6,     7,     8,        9,    4.5,    7.5,    9.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10]]


propies = []

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):
    if ingreso_datos[i][12] == 'xh24':
        Data = base.parse('xh24')

    for j in range(len(Data)):
        if ingreso_datos[i][13] == Data.values[j][0]:
            propies.append([Data.values[j][1], Data.values[j][2], Data.values[j][3]]) 

counters = []

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):

    b = propies [i][0]            
    c = propies [i][1]            
    d = propies [i][2]           
    e = np.sqrt((ingreso_datos[i][10]-ingreso_datos[i][8])**2+(ingreso_datos[i][11]-ingreso_datos[i][9])**2)    

    La_matriz = np.array([[ b*c/e,            0,           0,    -b*c/e,           0,            0],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**3,    c*d/e**2,         0,    c*d/e**3,     c*d/e**2],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**2,       c*d/e,         0,     c*d/e**2,      c*d/e],
                       [-b*c/e,            0,           0,     b*c/e,           0,           0],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**3,    c*d/e**2,         0,     c*d/e**3,    c*d/e**2],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**2,       c*d/e,         0,      c*d/e**2,    c*d/e]])


    # Matriz de ceros
    ceros_grande = np.zeros((36,36))

#    counters = ingreso_datos.loc[:, [2,3,4,5,6,7]]


    counters.append([ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3], ingreso_datos[i][4],
                     ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6], ingreso_datos[i][7]])


    for _, i1, i2, i3, j1, j2, j3 in counters():

        ceros_grande[:, [i1,i2,i3,j1,j2,j3]] = La_matriz
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, podrias editar tu pregunta y copiar exactamente la salida del error? Ahí viene más detalladamente qué linea de instrucción y porqué es la que falla. Por otra parte te sugeriria que evitaras nombres de variable tan genericos como i, o j (usa palabras como "index"), y que para acceder a los indices de las listas, puesto que sabes qué valores son los que contiene cada elemento(son constantes), que le des un nombre 
 en lugar de un número, por ejemplo "EDAD = 6" y lo usas en ingreso_datos[index][EDAD]

Comment: También veo que no terminas de entender los bucles for. En lugar de `for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)` puedes escribir `for indice, datos in enumerate(ingreso_datos)`. Con esto consigues un poco más de claridad porque la funcion `enumerate` devuelve el indice de cada elemento de la lista que recorres y queda un poco más conciso, aparte de que desempaquetas las variables individualmente, esto es: en el mismo bucle tienes el indice y la variable. Si me apuras tambien puedes prescindir del indice, pero esa explicación conlleva cambiar el concepto de tu código bastante, pero seria preferible.

Comment: Muy buenos días estimado, ya encontré el error y es justo lo que me comentas, mediante la función enumerate logré que me devuelva el índice de cada lista, y con esto llamo a una función que definí previamente.                                         `pivot_indice = indices_ensamble[0] 
    for indice_i, valor_i in enumerate(indices_ensamble): 
        rellenar_global(indice_i, valor_i)`.

Comment: También tomaré en cuenta eso de evitar nombres de variables genéricos, ya que como dices si que genera algo de confusión y muchas gracias por tu retroalimentación @Jose Rodriguez`, saludos cordiales.